# Debugging Issues in ASP.NET 4.7.2 Web Forms Deployment on IIS Server After Code Modification

Tags: iis, webforms, asp.net-4.6

I continued the existing project from the previous developer.

I would like to get some enlightenment as to why the data cannot be updated to the database when I add another code to the existing code file?

This project is developed using ASP.Net 4.7.2 Web Forms and deployed on IIS Server and I want to add some code for my task. But whenever I add getting error 500 - Internal Server Error. I have try troubleshoot on everything but nothing is working on the server.

By using the same code, when I try to debug on my localhost everything works fine. The page able to view and the value of the data field I add can be updated to the database.

But when I applied on Server, the page getting error 500 when I add new method function which is from my localhost it's working fine.

Is there any part I need to check?

[image: Error]

I have tried many things but nothing is working on server.

Comment: There is no guarantee the same code runs everywhere, and unhandled exceptions are common causes of the 500 error pages. What you might try is to debug directly on that server, as the actual call stacks/memory states can always help you get started. You can also improve application level logging to catch unhandled exceptions. That's too much for an online discussion, and you should consider hiring a consultant to teach you more.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to see details about 500 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Ive seen someone here with the exact same question. Is this like a teaxtbook project for an internship/uni or something?

Comment: What kind of publishing approach is being used here? Are you using the publish wizard? Or are you using a simple file copy of the aspx web page along with the aspx.cs (for c#), or aspx.vb.net (for vb.net).